# Enabling/disabling proftpd accounts with PHP and WHM

Tags: php, cpanel, ftp

I have a VPS with WHM/CPanel which is being used just by me.  It's utilizing proftpd.  I'd like to, via a PHP script, disable/enable a specific FTP account.  I've done this by having PHP call a bash script which removes/adds the user account line to /etc/proftpd/USERNAME password file.  However, in order to do this I have to give other write rights to /etc/proftpd/USERNAME.  This isn't ideal, and I'd be willing to do it another way.  It also seems like WHM is automatically resetting these permissions on a regular basis.  Does anybody have any ideas on a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

That's how file permissions work. If you want a user/group to have access to a file, then they need the permission to do it. If you don't want your PHP/Apache user to have access to that file, then you can't use PHP to do the enabling/disabling.

You could, however, create a separate user to run PHP as for this admin panel. This way the PHP admin panel is able to enable/disable FTP accounts, but your other PHP users won't have access to the file. One way to do this is through [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html).

Comment: How do you run PHP as multiple users though?

Comment: You can do that using [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html).